# Prevent Access from Changing Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Microsoft Access wants to be helpful and change my queries when underlying object (either form or query) does not exist.

For example, if I had a query that did the following...

```
SELECT FirstName
FROM persons
```

If the persons table does not exist yet, and I import the query, Access will place an "expr: " in front of FirstName signifying that it cannot find the column. This example table will be created with VBA later.

Is there a way to prevent Access from auto-correcting queries upon import?

Thanks!

Comment: When I attempt to use CREATE SQL DDL whose definition includes a table that does not exist I get an error... which is exactly the behaviour I desire. In fact, I think it should also error when trying to drop a table that is included in a VIEW definition. Creating VIEWed tables before the base tables makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the query to specify the aliases

```
SELECT FirstName AS FirstName
FROM Persons
```

This will prevent MS Acces from creating an alias for you. (Stupid I know, but it works.)

Comment: That addresses the example but not the general question. The Access UI screws up the SQL in saved database objects in other ways e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706383/prevent-access-screwing-up-queries-it-cant-understand-when-switching-to-design-m