# Prevent MS Access Automatically Updating Queries

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to prevent Access from updating a query, specifically removing a join, when a table no longer exists?

For example, the following query is used with a temporary table;

```
Select Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2
From   Table1 
  left join Table2 on Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
Where  Table2.Col1 is null
```

If the temporary table is subsequently dropped and the query opened Access drops the join resulting in;

```
Select Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2
From   Table1, Table2
Where  Table2.Col1 is null
```

This is similar to to the question asked at [Prevent Access from Changing Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830856/prevent-access-from-changing-queries)

Answer (score 0):

Try to [disable AutoCorrect](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-03.html), close and re-open your database and see if this still happens.

There may still be some cases where Access will 'do the right thing' and update your queries automatically.
In that case, you may use one of the following techniques:

- Keep the SQL in VBA code.
  You can bind the resulting SQL or re-create queries as necessary, for instance:

  ```vb
  ' Bind form to manually using the Form Open event '
  Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
      Dim sql As String
      sql = sql & "Select Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2 "
      sql = sql & "From   Table1 "
      sql = sql & "  left join Table2 on Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 "
      sql = sql & "Where  Table2.Col1 is null"
      ' Bind the form directly to the SQL '
      Me.RecordSource = sql
  End Sub
  ```
- Save the SQL of the Query to file, and re-load as needed:

  ```vb
  ' Save the query to a text file, in the application folder '
  Application.SaveAsText acQuery, "MyQuery", CurrentProject.Path & "\myQuery.txt"

  ' Load the the query from its previously saved file '
  Application.LoadFromText acQuery, "MyQuery", CurrentProject.Path & "\myQuery.txt"
  ```